# PHP Script how to disable a group of radio buttons after selecting one

Tags: php

I have this quiz in PHP script, I want to disable all multiple choice after clicked one of them.  How can I do this?  I have searched thru the web and below is the JavaScript I found. But how can I put this JavaScript in PHP?

JavaScript:

```
$("input:radio[name=level]").click(function(){
    var radios = document.formName.level;

        for (var i=0, iLen=radios.length; i<iLen; i++) {
          radios[i].disabled = true;
        } 
});
```

PHP script:

```
echo "<div class='news_poling disp_$pn'  $disp >";
                    echo "<input type='hidden' id='ans_$id' value='$ans'>";
                    echo "<div class='news_poling_top'><b>$lt</b>.$qns</div>";
                    echo "<div class='news_poling_sele-ct'><form id='polingForm' method='post' action='survey-script/polling-result.php'>";
                    echo "<div>
                    <input type='hidden' value='151' name='Qid'>
                    <fieldset class='radios' id='$id'>
                    <input type='radio' value='opt1' name='options_$id'  onclick=chkans(1,$id)>$opt1 $limit_tag
                    <input type='radio' value='opt2' name='options_$id' onclick=chkans(2,$id)>$opt2 $limit_tag";
                    if($opt3!='')
                    {echo "<input type='radio' value='opt3' name='options_$id' onclick=chkans(3,$id)>$opt3 $limit_tag ";}
                    if($opt4!='')
                    {echo "<input type='radio' value='opt4' name='options_$id' onclick=chkans(4,$id)>$opt4 $limit_tag ";}

                    echo "</fieldset>
                    </div>";

                    echo "</div>";

       echo "</div>";

   if($lt%$limit==0)
    $pn++;
  $lt++;
```

}

Comment: Why not have chkans disable them? It has the $id, so it can pull them up easily by name and disable them.

Comment: The PHP is irrelevant here. Post the rendered HTML and update the tags on your question.

Comment: PHP can not disable just after a selection is made. But by PHP, you can disable (change the structure of the form) whatever you want only after a submit. PHP is a server side lang. You always interact with the server first, then something changes*happen. What you need is javascript. (or jquery, a library written in javascript)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery for the rescue!

```
$(":radio[name='"+options_<?php echo $id ?>+"']").click(function(){
    $(this).attr("disabled", true); //Disable all
});
```

Comment: Hi all, thanks for your help. Felippe, i tried but it didnt work, any idea what went wrong?.